# Convert a QVariant of a custom type to a QString

Tags: qt4, qvariant

I have a custom class called Money that I have declared with Q_DECLARE_METATYPE().

```
class Money {
public:
  Money(double d) {
    _value = d;
  }
  ~Money() {}
  QString toString() const {
    return QString(_value);
  }
private:
  double _value;
};
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Money);

Money m(23.32);
```

I store that in a QVariant and I want to convert it to a QString:

```
QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(m);

QString s = v.toString();
```

Variable **s** ends up being a null string because QVariant doesn't know how to convert my custom type to the string. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found one way to do this.
I created a parent type called CustomType with a virtual method that I can implement to convert my custom type to a "normal" QVariant:

```
class CustomType {
public:
  virtual ~CustomType() {}
  virtual QVariant toVariant() const { return QVariant(); }
};
```

I then inherited my custom Money class from this.

```
class Money : public CustomType {
public:
  Money(double d) {
    _value = d;
  }
  ~Money() {}
  QVariant toVariant() {
    return QVariant(_value);
  }
private:
  double _value;
};
```

This allows me to pass my custom Money variables contained in QVariants so I can use them in the Qt property system, model/view framework, or the sql module.

But if i need to store my custom Money variable in the database (using QSqlQuery.addBindValue) it can't be a custom class, it has to be a known type (like double).

```
QVariant myMoneyVariant = myqobject.property("myMoneyProperty");
void *myData = myMoneyVariant.data();
CustomType *custType = static_cast<CustomType*>(myData);
QVariant myNewVariant = ct->toVariant();
```

**myNewVariant** now has the type of double, not Money so I can use it in a database:

```
myqsqlquery.addBindValue(myNewVariant);
```

or convert it to a string:

```
QString s = myNewVariant.toString();
```

Comment: I think the void *QVariant::data() method isn't in the Qt documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the following works?

> return QString(_value);

I don't seem to find a `QString` ctor that takes a `double`. You will have to do the conversion here yourself. The Qt way is to:

```
QString toString() const {
 QVariant d(_value);
 return d.ToQString();
}
```

Comment: You're right, there is no ctor that takes a double. I should have written that line as "return QString::number(_value);"

Comment: Either should fix your problem.

Comment: QVariant consumes more memory. QString::number(_value) is a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you try it this way?

```
class Money {
public:
  Money(double d) {
    _value = d;
  }
  ~Money() {}
  QString toString() const {
    return _value.toString();
  }
private:
  double _value;
};
```

Comment: You sure you can call a method on a native datatype?

Comment: Nope. double does not have a .toString() method. That wouldn't work.

Comment: Just replace the return _value.toString(); by return QVariant::number(_value);